# How to build a lookalike sample in SAS?

Tags: sas, sampling

I have 1 big dataset (A) and 1 small dataset (B). They all have the same variables. How do i take a sample out of the small dataset so that the distribution of each variable is roughly the same as the distribution in the big dataset?

The dataset will have 3 continuous variables: spend, age and height. I want to take deciles using proc univariate of A for each of the 3 variables.

So if 10% of group A has age between 10 and 20, I also want 10% of sample of B to have age between 10 and 20.

Comment: How do you define 'the distribution of each variable' ? How many variables are there?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question which I cannot completely answer.  My intuition tells me that this is a propensity score matching problem and ideally you should have a statistician to help you with this. (Refer to SAS documentation on PROC PSMATCH for details.)

As the question did not include data for a programmer to work with, I wrote some code to generate sample data.  Perhaps another programmer who wants to take a crack at solving this can use this data as a starting point...

```
/* --------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* This code will simulate data for this question                  */
/* --------------------------------------------------------------- */
data large_sample small_sample;
    /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* (1) Make a large dataset by outputting                      */
    /*     randomly selected records multiple times                */
    /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */
    do i=1 to 40000 ; 
       * normal distribution of age between 18 and 78;
       age = floor(18 + abs(rand("Normal", 0,1))*50);
       * normal distribution of height between 125 and 190 cm ; 
       height = floor(125 + abs(rand("Normal", 0,1))*65);
       * uniform distribution of height between 0 and 100 dollars ; 
       buy = ceil(ranuni(0)*100);
       output large_sample;
       
    end;
    /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* (2) Create Small sample data                                */
    /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */
    do i=1 to 400 ; 
       * uniform distribution of age between 18 and 78;
       age = 18 + ceil(ranuni(0))*60;   
       * uniform distribution of height between 125 and 190 cm ; 
       height = 125 + ceil(ranuni(0))*65;
       * uniform distribution of height between 0 and 100 dollars ; 
       buy = ceil(ranuni(0)*100);
       output small_sample;
    end;
run;

/* --------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Get target distributions                                        */
/* --------------------------------------------------------------- */
proc freq data=large_sample;
    table age    / out=target_age_dist;
    table height / out=target_height_dist;
run;
```